# Play a translated string from translate.google.com in a javafx application

Tags: javafx

I have the following code in JavaFX 8 that worked fine until a couple of weeks ago (I am not sure when it stoped working, as I did not realize it immediatly, it definitly worked well in JavaFX 2.2, but maybe google changed something (?)).

```
try {
  SpeechClip = new AudioClip("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q=Hello");
  SpeechClip.play(VoiceVolume);
} catch (MediaException me) {
  sLogger.error("Exception: " + me.getMessage());
}
```

What am I missing here? On the line ... new AudioClip... it now always ends up in the exception with "translate.google.com" as the content of me.getMessage(). Needless to say that the url works fine in Firefox (where it downloads a file of "translate_tts", without a file ending, like ".mp3").

Confused...

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Comment: what's the exception that's printing out now that it stopped working?

Comment: As said in the text: "translate.google.com" comes back in the exception...

Comment: From my log: 2014-03-19 14:18:41,586 [Thread-5] ERROR c3.MainFrameController  - >>> C3: Google not reachable, disabled speech for this session! Exception: translate.google.com

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb, but from that error, it seems like Google (and the internet) is unreachable. Perhaps make sure that you don't have any firewalls blocking access, and your internet is up and running. (The link worked fine for me, so I know the link is good).

Comment: Not very likely, as it is on the very same machine I am just browsing this page... proxy settings are fine... I can't figure it out...

Comment: I had the idea that maybe the file ending was missing and thus java can't create the audio clip, but I am not sure, because the exception message is so not-saying-anything...

Comment: does the javafx code work for you as well?

Comment: let me run it in my test javafx real quick.

Comment: Yea, i'm getting media unreachable as well, trying to figure out why now.

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you're right and google changed something. At least I can confirm that this is not specific to your platform. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will keep on looking into it. It is not the most important feature of my application, but still annoying..

Comment: Anyone has an idea on this?

Comment: I cannot get this to work and I have no idea, why! I know meanwhile that I get a MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE exception, but the media is accessible. Proxy settings do work fine in the same application for a database connection to the internet... I am completly puzzled.

Comment: I am now trying to download the file and get: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Welcome%20Warrior

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

Now it works again.